# spreadsheet graph on list of labelled data

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a list of typed data

```
type   date      value
A      1/1/2018  42
B      1/1/2018  12
C      2/2/2018  32
A      3/3/2018  48
C      3/3/2018  21
A      4/4/2018  12
```

Is it possible to create a graph showing the evolution of `value` of each `type` (A, B, and C => 3 curves) with respect to time (column `date`).

If possible, I would like to keep that table format.

Comment: I imagine that the issue depends on how you identify/group each data range. It sounds as though this is a particular _type_ of chart. It would probably help if you were to name it and/or show a sample (even hand drawn) of the chart that you want. Google has about a [dozen chart types](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190718?hl=en), possibly you can identify the type of chart that you think best suits your purpose.